# Adding Break Lines to Bot Framework while using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, deployment, botframework, markdown

I use Microsoft bot Framework and deployed it to Web Chat, my bot was printing the messages in a correct format as wanted with Break Lines "\n\n", then I use the following tutorial https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md to integrate JavaScript with my bot to remove the attachment icon (as shown in the figure below)
[image: This photo shows what I mean by the attachment icon]

After using JavaScript and removing the attachment icon I found that Break Lines (\n) was stopped working,

Does anyone know what did happen?

The previous format (without using JavaScript):

```
line1

line2
```

The current format (using JavaScript):

```
line1
line2
```

---

The following code was added in "wwwroot" to remove the attachment icon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
    (async function () {
            window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                {
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: "MY-TOKEN" }),
                    styleOptions: {
                        markdownRespectCRLF: true,
                        // hide upload button
                        hideUploadButton: true
                    }
                },
                document.getElementById('webchat')
            );

            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
        })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My c# code to Send Activity:

```
string reply = "Line 1 \n\n Line 2";
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(reply), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "remove the attached bottom"?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thanks, I have updated the question to clarify more.

Comment: You need to understand that `\n` is an escaped newline character that usually forms a line break and it's different from a blank line. Anyway, the problem is likely caused by different Markdown settings. Your bot can control how whitespace is formatted by specifying the activity's `TextFormat` property or even by adding a `text` property to the activity's channel data instead of using the activity's `Text` property. You can also experiment with different types of line breaks like `\r\n`. Can you provide the actual code for the activity that includes the `\n` so we can see how you're using it?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Appreciate your help.
Actually I tried many experiments include:
\r\n,
\n\n,
(2 spaces followed by \n followed by another 2 spaces and a \n)
and others, nothing works on **WebChat**, although they are worked on the **Emulator**.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yesterday, I tried using TextFormat property, after I had done long research, I had two options to display the welcome message:
The first is to use plain text, which allows adding a break line but not allows using bold font.                                      
The second is to use the markdown text, which allows using bold font but not allows using a break line.  
I need to use them both (break line and bold) :(

Comment: I am able to add blank lines in many different ways easily, in React Web Chat or otherwise. Are you using the minimal bundle perhaps? Also, you mention that you're encountering this behavior after removing the attachment icon. Please test this without removing the attachment icon to see if that has anything to do with this or if it's just irrelevant information.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes before using React it was working correctly, the following steps were followed to remove the attachment icon:
At first, installed package using "npm install botframework-webchat" 
Then, added the code to wwwroot (Note: the question above was updated to add the code).

In addition, the message which is contained break lines printed in the welcome dialog (C#).

Comment: @KyleDelaney While using the tutorial I think that this is a React but I found that JavaScript was used, I have updated the question, sorry for the confusion that occurs.

Comment: @KyleDelaney BTW, there is another thing that I want to add when the app was tested using online Web Chat (in Azure portal) and emulator it's working correctly, but the embedded version still not working.

Comment: I'm asking you to remove extraneous variables from your experiment in order to help diagnose the problem. We need to determine if the problem is because of React Web Chat or because of something you're doing on top of React Web Chat. So undo all of that stuff you did to remove the attachment icon. Just test with React Web Chat in its most basic form.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Alright, I tested it with JavaScript Web Chat in its most basic form and didn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. There's gotta be something weird going on with your bot code or your client code. Perhaps your bot is using some kind of middleware that's formatting the text. Please provide more relevant details about your bot if you can, and share the client code so we can see which version of Web Chat you're using. Also, try sending this string and tell me if you see any blank lines: `"1\n\n&nbsp;\n\n2\n\n\u00A0\n\n3\n\n\xA0\n\n4   \n5<br><br>6\n\n \n\n7  \r\n  \r\n8<br/><br/>9\n&nbsp;\n10  \n11"`

Comment: @KyleDelaney I tried to use `\n\n&nbsp;\n\n` and it is working correctly, appreciate your help, lots of gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have trouble inserting a blank line in a Bot Framework channel, you can try sending a message like this to see how the channel interprets various whitespace strings: `"1\n\n&nbsp;\n\n2\n\n\u00A0\n\n3\n\n\xA0\n\n4 \n5<br><br>6\n\n \n\n7 \r\n \r\n8<br/><br/>9\n&nbsp;\n10 \n11"`

Comment: I tried using this string and I get a single new line for 4 \n5 and 10 \n11. But If I use the same within adaptive card that does not work. Could you please help me here. @Kyle Delaney

Comment: This is the text within adaptive card
{
 "spacing": "small",
 "type": "TextBlock",
 "text": "07521102382, 07521102385, 07521102570,   \n07521102574\r\n",
 "size": "small",
 "horizontalAlignment": "left"
 }

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
message.Text = "your \n text";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
message.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message);
```

Comment: I tried to use plain text property, which allows me to add a break line but not allows using bold fon,  I want to use them both.

Answer (score 2):

**Try using this:**

`\n\n&nbsp;\n\n`