# Is it possible to include a line break (\ n) in the message from the user in imback of the processing of Adaptive Card in Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to include a line break (\ n) in the message from the user in imback of the processing of Adaptive Card in Teams?
I tried the following but I couldn't.
・ "\n\n"
・ "  \n"

Comment: I understand your question but can you share your card definition and a sample of what the output looks like? You can also try https://adaptivecards.io/designer/.

Comment: Could you please try out the sample mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#formatting-cards-with-markdown) in adaptive card designer and see if that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Break Lines to Bot Framework while using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188545/adding-break-lines-to-bot-framework-while-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You should replace `\n\n` with `\n\n\n\n‌‌ \n\n\n\n`

See https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1738#issuecomment-954100582

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).